# Keep alive xmpp client presence on Production

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmpppy

I am using **xmpppy** python library to for client implementation. What is the right way to keep alive **xmpp** client presence on Production?

XMPP Server: **ejabberd**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the TCP/IP connection alive by sending space at regular interval. This is neutral at the XMPP level if sent between stanzas.

Comment: Yes, that is right but I want to deploy it with Django on production... How should I deploy as service which should keep running?? and what kind of service it will be??